# Multiplicative order of root of unity modulo prime ideal of cyclotomic field

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, roots-of-unity

Let $n \geq 1$ be an integer, let $\zeta$ be a primitive $n$th root of unity, and let $P$ be a prime ideal of the ring of integers of $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta)$.

What is the multiplicative order of $\zeta$ modulo $P$?

By multiplicative order I mean the least integer $k \geq 1$ such that $\zeta^k \equiv 1 \bmod P$. Let's call it $\operatorname{ord}_P(\zeta)$. I am particularly interested in the case in which $\operatorname{ord}_P(\zeta) = n$ so that $\zeta$ is somehow a primitive $n$th root of unity "modulo $P$".

It is easy to see that $\operatorname{ord}_P(\zeta)$ divides $\gcd(n, N(P) - 1)$, but I could not find more information.

Thank

Answer (score 1):

"Usually" it's $n$. It can only be less than $n$ if $P$ contains an element $\zeta^m-1$
where $m$ is a proper factor of $n$. That only occurs when $P\cap\Bbb Z=p\Bbb Z$
where $p$ is a factor of $n$, so only at the finitely many ideals "over" a prime
factor of $n$.

Comment: Could you explain why $\zeta^m - 1 \in P$ implies that $P$ lies over a prime factor of $n$, please?

Comment: Consider the norm of $\zeta^m-1$.

Comment: If $m$ divides $n$, then $\zeta^m$ is a $(n / m)$th primitive root of unity. Hence the minimal polynomial of $\zeta^m - 1$ is $\Phi_{n / m}(X + 1)$, and the norm of $\zeta^m - 1$ is $\Phi_{n / m}(1)$, which is $1$ if $n/m$ is not a prime power, and $p$ if $n / m = p^k$ is a prime power. If $\zeta^m - 1 \in P$ then $P$ divides the principal ideal $(\zeta^m - 1)$ and so $N(P)$ divides $N(\zeta^m - 1)$, that is, $N(P) = p$ and $n = mp^k$. Does it make sense?